# panelizer content not displaying

Tags: 7, theming, panels

I have installed and enabled the [panelizer](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer) module and enabled the node_view template system page on the Page Manager administer pages page. I enabled panelizer for the `Basic Page` content type and created a new page. I clicked the panelizer tab and used the builder layout to create a new row below my body content. I added a region to the row and used the menu to add an existing node to that region.

It looked fine it preview so I saved it and went checked out the actual page where I saw the node content but not any of the panelizer content. The content in my added rows and regions did not display.

I tried uninstalling panelizer and re-installing but it still isn't working. Did I forget something?

Comment: Have you read the Installing Panelizer section in module page ?

Comment: @NikhilM yes I followed the steps. download install and enable the module, enable node_view in pages manager, configure panelizer to enable it for the node type.

Comment: Did your content suddenly appear after clearing all of your caches? I'm experiencing this issue, but my content comes back after drush cc all.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you enable panels node template at admin/structure/pages.

Comment: It's a shame how I forget this all the time!

Answer (score 1):

Panelizer 7.3.1 I had this same problem.

Panelized content shows preview, but when I view the live page, it looked like a regular, un-panelized node.

Turned on and off everything I could think of. Pulled out my hair...

Finally, I looked at the Display tab of my content type, and clicked open the Custom Display Settings. I turned OFF "use custom display settings for view modes: Full Content and Teaser". Suddenly my nodes were panelized. Click back on "Full Content", and panels disappear.

I don't know why this matters. Also, I'm using only Default-Panelize & Default-Provide Default Panel for my content type in the Panelize Configuration page.